# Clearing the queue with ncftp

Tags: ftp, ftp-client

How to clear the queue in ncftpbatch / ncftp.

I once could not upload a file and ncftp batch tries to upload the file forever.

No every time I try to upload a file per ftp in batch an error says there is a missing file. 
So how can I clear the Queue ?

Answer (score 3):

In linux or unix systems you should clear files in `~/.ncftp/spool`

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

simply delete all files in C:\Users\user\ncftp\spool